# Javascript for loop performance

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, for-loop

I usually write for loops in javascript like so

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
    var item = array[i];
}
```

After having looked through some Google code (MarkerClusterer API) I see they frequently use a slightly different way to construct their for loops

```
for (var i = 0, item; item = array[i]; i++) { }
```

Is this second way faster or better in anyway, or is it simply style?

Comment: Basically, in the second loop you are waiting for an undefined element to get out. But what if an element of the array is undefined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second loop will be faster :

It only checks for an undefined variable to break out of the loop, no comparison and no accessing array length.

Here is a comparison : http://jsperf.com/loop-comare-js

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Any difference in performance is likely to be:

- negligible in size
- implementation dependent

This should be considered just a matter of style and preference.

It should be noted that the two loops aren't quite equivalent: one takes items until it reaches array.length; the other takes items until it reaches an undefined item.

Answer (score 1):

The second is probably faster because you avoid accessing `array.length` in its iteration.

The alternative that allegedly is also faster than the first one, is:

```
for(var i=0, j=array.length; i<j; i++)
```

again because you call `array.length` only once. If you really want a deep insight into the various `for-loop` cases performance, check [this jsperf page](http://jsperf.com/loops/70)

But the performance improvement most of the time is negligible compared to other parts of the app that you can improve and the inherent delays in I/O that are orders of magnitude more time consuming than improving the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is faster especially in old browsers.

Instead of calculating array length on every iteration you precalculate it once and then use the stored value.

Comment: Note that the length is not calculated when it is accessed. It is update when the array is mutated.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is faster, expecially if you don't do anything in the loop... see DhruvPathak answer and his JsPerf.

When you do something inside the loop there are solutions even faster than that one:

http://jsperf.com/js-array-iteration-meh/12